# Understanding Chef's run_list, particularly 'recipe[COOKBOOK]'

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have read through the run_list manual on Chef's website and couldn't find my answer...

I have a cookbook named "breakfast"

and I have a role config file that defines a run list as:

```
"run_list": [
    "recipe[breakfast::egg]",
    "recipe[breakfast::bread]",
    "recipe[breakfast]"
]
```

Based on the above, I know that the recipe "egg.rb" and "bread.rb" is being run from /cookbooks/breakfast/recipes/

My question is, for the 3rd recipe on the run list definition "recipe[breakfast]", what is being run exactly? Is it /cookbooks/breakfast/recipes/default.rb?

thanks in advance!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if only the cookbook's name is specified and the recipe name is not, it means that the `default` recipe is run. That is so not only in run_list, but also when you include 1 recipe in another like that:

```
include_recipe 'breakfast' # will run breakfast::default recipe
```